# AVAudioEngine: any way to control buffer size (latency)?

Tags: macos, core-audio, avaudioengine

I've written a V3 AudioUnit and have hosted it using `AVAudioUnit`. My render callback is called with 512 frames, which is too high latency for my app (a synthesizer).

**Is there a way with `AVAudioEngine` to set the processing buffer size? Or do I need to use CoreAudio directly?**

Note: this is on OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following did the trick:

```
static OSStatus SetCurrentIOBufferFrameSize(AudioUnit inAUHAL,
                                        UInt32 inIOBufferFrameSize)
{
  return AudioUnitSetProperty(inAUHAL,
                              kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSize,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              0,
                              &inIOBufferFrameSize, sizeof(UInt32));
}
```

...

```
_audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
SetCurrentIOBufferFrameSize(_audioEngine.inputNode.audioUnit, 32);
```

Comment: THANKS YOU SOOOOO MUCH!

Comment: Not able to implement the latency.

Comment: Wouldn't the following be enough? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616589-setpreferrediobufferduration?language=objc

Comment: @SevenSystems That's for iOS.